# Append to an existing backup setup when doing a Transaction Log backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log, best-practices

When doing transaction log backups, is it best practice to just keep appending to the same file or creating a new .trn file for each backup?

Answer (score 2):

I personally create a whole new NTFS file for each backup. Why? Because there is no chance of accidentally overwriting a backup (with init). A lost transaction log backup is crippling. In my opinion, the maintenance overhead of multiple backup devices/files is negligible.